# Swipe left/right to kill apps does stop service

Tags: android, service

I have tried almost everything like START_STICKY, BroadcastReceiver but all these things are not really working to restart the service. Is there any other way to restart the service in android version 5.0 and above

Comment: It's impossible to have a `Service` run continuously. That's not something Android was designed for. Consider another approach which doesn't require a constantly running `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

START_STICKY will restart the service but it will take time sometimes 10 sec sometimes 10 min .. sometimes never. Depends on android system memory usage.

U can implement a foreground service but it will create a dialog in swipe down.This will keep the activity running.

Apps like WhatsApp,Facebook uses push notifications along with intent service to restart service when a message arrives.

Comment: do you really thing 10 sec or 10 min require for restarting service

Comment: android system queues the threads .. so when our service is killed .. if there is sufficient memory left (and other conditions met) android will restart our service,  else it will end up in queue waiting for its turn.